# "Merge" table row-by-row in R

Tags: r

I have two (or more) tables of equal dimensions in **R**.

```
table1 <- as.table(matrix("TOP", nrow=4, ncol=2 )) 
table2 <- as.table(matrix("BOTTOM", nrow=4, ncol=2 )) 
> table1
  A   B  
A TOP TOP
B TOP TOP
C TOP TOP
D TOP TOP
> table2
  A      B     
A BOTTOM BOTTOM
B BOTTOM BOTTOM
C BOTTOM BOTTOM
D BOTTOM BOTTOM
```

I want to bind them together row-by-row. By contrast, `rbind` gives me

```
> rbind(table1,table2)
  A        B       
A "TOP"    "TOP"   
B "TOP"    "TOP"   
C "TOP"    "TOP"   
D "TOP"    "TOP"   
A "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
B "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
C "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
D "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
```

when what I want is

```
 > something(table1,table2, byrow=TRUE)
   A        B       
  A "TOP"    "TOP"   
  A "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"  
  B "TOP"    "TOP"   
  B "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
  C .....
```

Comment: You can add a value column with integers from 1 to nrow() and sort the "rdinded" tables

Comment: Also give a try to `data.table`, it is a package that enhance `data.frame`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `interleave` from the "gdata" package:

```
> library(gdata)
> interleave(table1, table2)
  A        B       
A "TOP"    "TOP"   
A "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
B "TOP"    "TOP"   
B "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
C "TOP"    "TOP"   
C "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
D "TOP"    "TOP"   
D "BOTTOM" "BOTTOM"
```

Comment: Even simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like @Ananda's solution.  If you'd like to stick with base R:

```
t(mapply(rbind, table1, table2))
```

---

While it's not completely clear what the ultimate goal, I'm guessing you are making multiple calls to `table` and then looking to have them unified nicely.

it might be easier to use a `data.table` and then you can simply run

```
myDT[..., table(<variables>), by=<someFactor>]
```

Comment: I have three sets of model statistics, and I want to show them coefficient-by-coefficient rather than type-by-type. So in this case, I think turning them into a data table would not be the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @gmacfarlane, judging by what you describe here, do be sure to read the help page for `interleave` and run the examples (`library(gdata); example(interleave)`). I think one of the examples is similar to what you might be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt at handcrafting:

```
stopifnot(nrow(table1)==nrow(table2))
interleaved <- rep(seq(nrow(table1)),each=2)+c(0,nrow(table1))
rbind(table1,table2)[interleaved,]
```